# Connecting two routers together

Tags: networking, vpn, router

I have a d-Link DIR615 router provided to me by my ISP, and a Vigor2900G router. I used to have the Vigor router as my main router, but since I upgraded my internet connection and speed, the Vigor can't reach the max speed, whereas the d-Link can. I want to connect these two routers together so that the d-Link will still serve as the primary router and the Vigor as a VPN server, but I can't seem to accomplish this. All of my devices are connected to a 16-port Dell switch.

Can someone possibly help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a DMZ VLAN on the Dell switch, adding the Vigor and D-Link router ports to it, and on the D-Link, port-forward the VPN port (whatever you are using) to the Vigor's IP.  The Vigor will have another foot in the internal network so it can route VPN traffic to the internal network.

*Internet > DLink (WAN interface) > Dell (DMZ VLAN) > Vigor (DMZ VLAN) > VPN connection processing on Vigor > Vigor (Internal VLAN) > Dell (Internal VLAN) > Internal IPs (on Internal VLAN)*